# IndexPathForSelectedRow returns null

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsindexpath

I am using a `fetchresultscontroller` returning distinct results (`NSDictionaryResultType`) which has multiple sections and rows in each section. When I use `indexPathForSelectedRow` it returns `null`. Here is my code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{       
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toDetailViewSeg"]){
        WLDetailTableViewController *detailController =segue.destinationViewController;
        WeightLiftingInfo *theInfo = [[_fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
        detailController.muscleGroupInfo = [theInfo valueForKey:@"muscleGroup"];
        detailController.specificExerciseInfo = [theInfo valueForKey:@"specificExercise"];
        detailController.managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
    }

}
```

How do I get the correct index path??

Comment: This question looks suspiciously similar ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9073309/335858)). I am not 100% sure, so I wouldn't vote on closing this as a duplicate.

Comment: Please remove the branch of the `if`-statement that doesn't get executed.

Comment: Try using `[sender indexPathForSelectedRow]` as suggested by _a comment_ to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8130716/608157)

Comment: The title is very identical, but the situation I believe, is different. The IndexPathForSelectedRow worked perfectly until I wanted  to fetch distinct results. I was thinking it might have to do with the return result being an NSDictionary??

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist `[sender indexPathForSelectedRow]` throws an invalidargumentexception

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"Sender: %@", [sender class]);` so we can see what's actually triggering the seque.

Comment: @PhillipMills the class triggering it is `UITableViewCell`

Comment: I tried the following code and it is working again. Thank you for your help!

`WeightLiftingInfo *theInfo = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];`

Comment: @user1410832 Nice. Post it as answer to your own question (if it was your solution) and accept it so that people know that there is an answer for your question.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist SO tells me I cant answer my own question until 8 hours after the original post due to my low reputation ( I'm new here). I posted the answer, but SO wont let me accept it until tomorrow. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
WeightLiftingInfo *theIndo = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

This seems to be the answer. It provides the correct index path which looks like a set [x,y] instead of a single integer. (this is my interpretation which may be wrong)