# How do I get my text from a label to show up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I am using a table view to display different contact information, and depending on which one you pick there will be the details for that specific resource. I had the code working but I moved projects, so I'm not sure why my labels aren't showing up. I have a list of state contacts and then you push one which leads to the detail. Here is my code:

StateContacts.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface StateContacts : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate,
UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

StateContacts.m

```
#import "StateContacts.h"
#import "State.h"

@interface StateContacts ()

@end

@implementation StateContacts 
{
    NSArray *state;
    NSArray *num;
    NSArray *fax;
}

@synthesize tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data
    state = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Child Abuse Hotline", @"Drug Lab Remediation", @"Prevent Suicide TN", @"TN Crime Vict. Comp.", @"TN Department of Education", @"TN Homeland Security", @"TN State Police", @"TN Supreme Court", nil];
    num = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"(111) 111-1111", @"(222) 222-2222", @"(333) 333-3333", @"(444) 444-4444", @"(555) 555-5555", @"(666) 666-6666", @"(777) 777-7777", @"(888) 888-8888", nil];
    fax = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"n/a", @"n/a", @"n/a", @"n/a", @"n/a", @"n/a", @"n/a", @"n/a", nil];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [state count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"myCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [state objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showStateInfo"]) 
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        State *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.stateName = [state objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.pName = [num objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.fName = [fax objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
@end
```

State.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface State : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *stateLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *pNumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *fNumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *stateName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *pName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *fName;

@end
```

State.m

```
#import "State.h"

@interface State ()

@end

@implementation State

@synthesize stateLabel;
@synthesize stateName;
@synthesize pNumber;
@synthesize fNumber;
@synthesize pName;
@synthesize fName;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Set the Label text
    stateLabel.text = stateName;
    //number and fax in array
    pNumber.text = pName;
    fNumber.text = fName;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

I know a lot of people have had this problem before, and I've tried what they suggest such as making sure the segues are connected properly and cleaning and rebuilding. Still nothing is showing up for the label. My hierarchy is correct with UIView. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3s7V.png) is my storyboard and the connections for state detail and StateContacts. I just don't know what else to try.

Comment: try populating the values in `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad` in `State.m`. Also try to `NSLog` the values of `stateName`, `pName` and `fName`

Comment: One more thing! I'm unable to see the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method in your `StateContacts.m` class. I think your `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];` is not returning a valid value because i think no table cell is selected! Kindly confirm this as well!

Comment: Do you mean to only have viewWillAppear and not viewDidLoador or to have both? Also, I'm not sure I understand why I need a tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath method if I have the line with NSIndexPath. Thank you for the help

Comment: `viewDidLoad` gets called only per the lifecycle of the view controller. But `viewWillAppear` gets called each time the view appears before the user. So i suggest you to set your labels' text in `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`

Comment: `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` gets called each time you click a cell in a `tableView`. Maybe this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073309/indexpathforselectedrow-returning-nil

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIOR thank you, I rewrote the class basically and only included the methods necessary. I also used a View Controller with a table view instead of a Table view controller. I think that was with a tutorial I was using so it was clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code incorrectly defines a `tableView` property that hides the original `tableView` property inherited from UITableView. To fix this, simply delete the property and the corresponding `@synthesize` directive. While you're at it, you can also delete the `@synthesize` directives in the State class, since the compiler now auto synthesizes properties by default.

Note that once you've deleted the redundant outlet, you may need to reconnect it in Interface Builder, so be sure to double-check that.