# Swift: Passing data from a tableView in a ViewController to another ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to pass the indexPath.row data from the selected cell to the next view controller using both the didSelectCellAtIndexPath and the prepareForSegue methods but the value isnt passing through.

Code for both ViewControllers is show below:

```
   import UIKit

class MainMenu: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

// array of the menu options

let mainMenuOptions = ["Exercises 1", "Exercises 2", "Exercises 3"]

// UITableView

@IBOutlet weak var exerciseOptions: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    exerciseOptions.delegate = self
    exerciseOptions.dataSource = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Table configuration

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "ExercisesTableViewCells"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExercisesTableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.text = mainMenuOptions[indexPath.row]
    return cell
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

// Segue to VC based on row selected
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0{
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueToExercises", sender: self)
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1{
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueToExercises", sender: self)
    }
    else{
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueToReminders", sender: self)
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "SegueToExercise"){

        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as? ExerciseMenu
        viewController!.mainMenuValue = exerciseOptions.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row


    }

}
```

For the Second View Controller:

```
   import UIKit

class ExerciseMenu: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var exerciseOptionsTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var exerciseOptionsTable: UITableView!
@IBAction func beginWorkout(sender: AnyObject) {
}

// receives data from MainMenu
var mainMenuValue: Int!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    exerciseOptionsTable.delegate = self
    exerciseOptionsTable.dataSource = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "ExerciseMenuCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExercisesTableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.text = String(mainMenuValue)
    return cell
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073309/indexpathforselectedrow-returning-nil) thread for possible explanations for this behavior.
The first step of troubleshooting would be to put a breakpoint in your prepareForSegue method to see if `exerciseOptions.indexPathForSelectedRow` is already nil at that point, in which case something is happening before the segue even occurs that's messing with the value (which the link above can help you diagnose).

Try making a property in your table view controller called something like selectedRow, and in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, set `self.selectedRow = indexPath.row`. This way you have your own variable that'll be more reliable than `exerciseOptions.indexPathForSelectedRow`. Then change the code in `prepareForSegue` appropriately. So to give you the full methods as I'm envisioning them:

(As a property of the first view controller) `var selectedRow: Int?`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

  if indexPath.row == 0{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueToExercises", sender: self)
    self.selectedRow = 0
  }
  else if indexPath.row == 1{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueToExercises", sender: self)
    self.selectedRow = 1

  }
  else{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueToReminders", sender: self)
    self.selectedRow = indexPath.row
  }
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if (segue.identifier == "SegueToExercise"){

    let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as? ExerciseMenu
    viewController!.mainMenuValue = self.selectedRow!


  }
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm still learning Swift, so my judgment regarding optionals/optional unwrapping might be unideal for a technical reason I'm not aware of, but the overall theory here is sound, I think.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I applied your suggested method, adding a print(selectedRow) after each of the if statements. They returned Optional (0), Optional (1) and Optional(2) respectively, but printing mainMenuValue in viewDidLoad() returns nil. any suggestions?

Comment: I also added a print(selectedRow) statement to the prepareForSegue function and it returned nil

Comment: Hrmmm, I'm not sure. Just for kicks, what happens if you just hardcode selectedRow = 1 (or any other Int) in the first View Controller's viewDidLoad? Is it still nil when you get to prepareForSegue? Oh, also try explicitly making selectedRow strong?

Comment: Oh! And maybe I screwed up by placing the selectedRow assignment under the performSegue call! So try doing selectedRow = 0/1/etc. BEFORE calling performSegue. I should have caught that.

Comment: I changed your code to put it before the performSegue function when i originally changed it, still no solution unfortunately

Comment: HURRAY! I've managed to fix the issue by removing the if (segue.identifier == "SegueToExercise") conditional statement in the prepareForSegue function

Comment: Had you checked to make sure that the code inside that if-statement was ever actually being executed?

Comment: Sorry for the comment spam. The problem was so stupid! in the if statement the segue is called "SegueToExercise" but the segue identifier is actually called "SegueToExercises". Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Classic! No problem, I'm glad that the world makes sense after all.